# Column with Numeric DataType returns a value with decimal upon using Crystal Report

Tags: sql, vb6, crystal-reports, numeric, sqldatatypes

SQL Server 7.0 
VB 6.0 
Crystal Report 8

Column Name: myColumn 
Data Type: numeric 
Length: 9 
Precision: 10 
Scale: 0 
Lets say myColumn has a value of: 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5
When I check it on Enterprise manager and Query analyzer, the results are fine. 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5
But whenever I fetch the data on crystal report using vb, the results are: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just sounds like the number format in your report is set to give a decimal by default. if you change the formatting in the report it should fix your issue

Comment: Hi MD-Tech, thanks! I checked the field on the report and the fields DecimalPlaces property was set to '2' (by Default). I changed it to '0' and it works. Thanks, cheers mate.

Comment: my super power is checking the supposedly bleeding obvious since thats usually where everyone else forgets to look because its quite so bleeding obvious ;) thanks for confirming my answer